# How to pass code into a function verbatimly?

Tags: r

I want to define a function so that it takes some code as its argument and runs the following in the function body.

```
sink(stderr())
# my code
sink()
```

The code has to be taken verbatimly. For example, if the code is `x=1; print('abc')`, then the function should be called as

`tostderr({ x=1; print('abc') })`

The variable `x` should be available after running the above command.

```
tostderr=function(expr
  , envir = parent.frame()
  , enclos = if(is.list(envir) || is.pairlist(envir)) parent.frame() else baseenv()) {
  sink(stderr())
  eval.parent(substitute(eval(quote(expr), envir, enclos)))
  sink()
}
```

I tried the above code, but I got something like this. How to fix the problem?

```
R> tostderr({ print('abc') })
Error in eval(quote({ : object 'envir' not found
Calls: tostderr -> eval.parent -> eval -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

Comment: Replace `eval.parent(...)` with `eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos)`?

Comment: `x=1` still not there in `ls() debug at #4:sink(stderr()) Browse[3]> expr
[1] "abc"`

Comment: Probably not desired, and with @MikaelJagan change: `my_kitchen_sink <- tostrerr2({print('abc');'x=1'})`, `debug at #6: sink()
Browse[2]> expr
[1] "abc"
[1] "x=1"`